# Press a Button in React Native Elements UI Toolkit to go to a web URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-native

i'm new in this, and i try to make a social media button using

```
import { SocialIcon } from 'react-native-elements';
```

and using

```
<SocialIcon type='facebook'/>
```

but how send the URL in the `OnPress( )`. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [Linking in React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#opening-external-links):

> To start the corresponding activity for a link (web URL, email,
>   contact etc.), call:
>
> ```
> Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
> ```

You can swap the `url` for the real URL, wrap it in a very specific handler passed into your `SocialIcon` component's `onPress` prop, or (and this is much more React-y), you can create a reusable component, i.e.:

```js
class SocialButton extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    Linking.openURL(this.props.url).catch(err => console.error("An error occurred", err));
  };

  render() {
    return <SocialIcon type={this.props.type} url={this.props.url} onPress={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}
```

and use it the following way:

```js
<SocialButton type="facebook" url="https://www.facebook.com/wonderloveapp/" />
```